# accepts_nested_attributes_for hard code in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am writing a code stuff for API. Where i am assigning parameters to the class fields.

I have relationship,
   event_file.rb

```
 has_many :event_file_attachments
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_file_attachments
```

event_file_attachment.rb

```
mount_uploader :attachment, EventFileUploader
belongs_to :event_file
```

Wanted to take the value from JOSN and write into nested attribute,

JOSN,

```
{"event_files"=>{"event_id"=>"1"}, "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xc16e4e4 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141226-5521-12zezuk>, @original_filename="asset.JPG", @content_type="image/jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"asset.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n">}
```

In controller,

```
data = params[:event_files]


      @event_file = EventFile.new(:event_member_ids => data['event_member_ids'],
                        :user_id => current_user.id,
                        :company_id => @current_company.id,
                        :event_id => data['event_id'],
                        :status => 0)
      @event_file.save

      @event_file_attachment = EventFileAttachment.new(:event_file_id => @event_file.id,
                                                       :status => 0,
                                                       :attachment => params[:attachment])
      @event_file_attachment.save
```

And this is a wrong way to save the nested attribute, How to modify and optimize the code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association you created along with the `accepts_nested_attribute_for` method will create a `event_file_attachments_attributes` on which you can add the corresponding event file attachment attributes, here is a quick example:

**In the controller:**

```
@event_file = EventFile.new(:event_member_ids => data['event_member_ids'],
                    :user_id => current_user.id,
                    :company_id => @current_company.id,
                    :event_id => data['event_id'],
                    :status => 0,
                    :event_file_attachments_attributes => [{"0" => {:attr1 => "value", :attr2 => "value"}},{"1" => {:attr1 => "value", :attr2 => "value"}}])
```

For mor information on this you can check a really helpful railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Thank you, I have did :event_file_attachments_attributes => {"0" => {:attr1 => "value", :attr2 => "value"}}, removed the array it's working fine..